# Foreach with array with associotive arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm not able to find (or don't know what to search properly) how to loop through associotive arrays in arrays. Correct me if my description of the problem is wrong..

Returned data:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [post_id] => 9
        [post_title] => Constante synchronisatie met Git
        [post_content] => Git is een vrij gedistribueerd versiebeheersysteem. Het wordt ook wel een softwarebroncode-managementproject genoemd. De nadruk ligt op snelheid. Git is oorspronkelijk gemaakt door Linus Torvalds voor de ontwikkeling van de Linuxkernel.  Iedere Git werkmap bevat de volledige repository met een compleet historisch overzicht en volledige trackingcapaciteiten. Git is niet afhankelijk van een gemeenschappelijke locatie of een centrale server zoals het 'Concurrent Versions System' (CVS) of Subversion (SVN).
        [post_date] => 2016-09-20
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [post_id] => 10
        [post_title] => Hybride React apps schrijven d.m.v. Git
        [post_content] => Node.js is een softwareplatform waarop men applicaties kan ontwikkelen en draaien. Die applicaties worden geschreven in JavaScript, maar in tegenstelling tot veel andere Javascript-toepassingen, worden die niet uitgevoerd in een webbrowser, maar in de JavaScript-Engine van Node.js zelf, die op de server draait. De applicaties kunnen draaien op elke computer waarop de Node.js runtime is geïnstalleerd, dat kan Windows, Mac OS X of Linux zijn.
        [post_date] => 2016-09-20
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [post_id] => 11
        [post_title] => React en Angular vergeleken
        [post_content] => AngularJS, vaak aangeduid als Angular, is een opensource webapplicatieframework dat wordt onderhouden door Google en een collectief van individuele ontwikkelaars en bedrijven die bezig zijn de mogelijkheden voor het ontwikkelen van Single Page Applications (SPA) te verbeteren. Het doel is het vereenvoudigen van zowel de ontwikkeling als het testen van dergelijke applicaties door het aanbieden van een framework voor client-side model-view-controller (MVC)-architectuur, samen met componenten die gewoonlijk worden gebruikt in Rich Internet Applications.
        [post_date] => 2016-09-20
    )
)
```

I've tried using `foreach()` within `foreach()` nestling through the arrays, with no luck. Help is appriciated!

Comment: Hi. Post what you've tried.  And your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreach to use through the array :

```
foreach($data as $item){
    echo $item['post_id'] . ' -> ' . $item['post_title'];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! You saved myself a headache :)

Comment: @Uberfume Great. If the answer suits you, you can accept it by clicking on the green check image next to it.

Comment: Was about to , but had to wait 5min before i could submit answer and forgot after on :)